# Get all the objects (DOM or otherwise) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

**The short version:**

- How can I get a list of all the objects (including their descendant
     objects) on the page (not just the first-depth objects)?
  - **Anticipated subproblem**:      How can I track
       the visited objects as I walk the objects?

Thanks in advance.

---

---

**The long version (with background!!):**

Using the `in` keyword we can get all the properties of an object. (And using the `hasOwnProperty` method allows us to filter out only the properties that belong to that object and not the inherited ones.)

```
for (var prop in obj) {
   if (typeof(obj[prop]) == 'object'  && obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            showObjectsOfInternal(obj[prop], visitedObjects); // recursion.
   }
}
```

That is a good starting point, but I would like to get all the objects.  One could imagine iterating through all the properties and accumulating the objects, then recursively iterating through those.  However, if there was an object reference loop, like an object referred to itself, such as in `window.window`, it would be good not to get trapped by that.  So one needs a way to track all the 'visited objects' during the recursion.

To track the visited object, one really needs a hashset of objects, based on their internal object key.  I tried that by making a `visitedObjects` object and setting it's keys as the object to be added, and the value didn't matter.

```
if(visitedObjects[obj] == 1){return;}
visitedObjects[obj] = 1;
```

But that didn't work for me.  (It seems to turn the objects into strings for keys, instead of using their internal reference keys)

So instead I decided to use an array and add an `indexOf` method.

```
Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj){
   for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
   {
      if(this[i] == obj) // reference comparison for non-primitive objects.
      {
         return i;
      }  
   }
   return -1; 
}
```

But that didn't work either (eventually I got that I couldn't do `for(var prop in obj)` even though the object wasn't null!  The debugger said that obj did not support that property.)

In any case, here is my buggy code:

```
function showObjectsOf(obj) {
    var objHolder = new Array();
    var ancestorNames = new Array();
    ancestorNames.push('obj');
    showObjectsOfInternal(obj, objHolder, ancestorNames);
}
function showObjectsOfInternal(obj, visitedObjects, ancestorNames) {
    if (visitedObjects.indexOf(obj) != -1) {
        return;
    }
    visitedObjects.push(obj);
    alert(getAncestorString(ancestorNames));
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (typeof (obj[prop]) == 'object') {
            ancestorNames.push(prop);
            showObjectsOfInternal(obj[prop], visitedObjects, ancestorNames);
            ancestorNames.remove(prop);
        }
    }
}
function getAncestorString(ancestorNames) {
    return ancestorNames.join('.');
}

Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] == obj) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
Array.prototype.remove = function(obj){
    var ind = this.indexOf(obj);
    if(ind != -1)
    {
        this.splice(ind,1);
    }
}
window.onload = function() { showObjectsOf(window); };
```

**Update**
Actually, the dictionary may be the better way to go.  It just wasn't working for me in IE.  works fine in chrome though.

Comment: Define "on the page". Do you mean DOM elements? Do you mean the entire object tree under the global object?

Comment: Also, what could you possibly want to do with all those objects?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I suppose I mean the entire object tree under the global object.  I guess the entire object tree under any given object is what I want as a subproblem.

Comment: [So you want this, right?](http://memegenerator.net/cache/instances/400x/11/11735/12017518.jpg) `:P`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Well, there are several things I can think of.  However my motivation came from my last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392193/determine-stack-depth-in-javascript-using-javascript .  I want to change all the functions on the page.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I can't view the link atm but I imagine it's pretty funny.  And yes, probably.

Comment: Why? Why do you need this method? Also your looking for `console.dir(window)`

Comment: @user420667: if your motivation is debugging IE as your other question suggests, I think you'll be disappointed with the accepted answer (it won't work).

Comment: @Raynos: Thanks.  I wanted to do it programmatically, so the code itself could be slightly altered to do other things.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My quick attempt:

```
var objs = []; // we'll store the object references in this array

function walkTheObject( obj ) {
    var keys = Object.keys( obj ); // get all own property names of the object

    keys.forEach( function ( key ) {
        var value = obj[ key ]; // get property value

        // if the property value is an object...
        if ( value && typeof value === 'object' ) { 

            // if we don't have this reference...
            if ( objs.indexOf( value ) < 0 ) {
                objs.push( value ); // store the reference
                walkTheObject( value ); // traverse all its own properties
            } 

        }
    });
}

walkTheObject( this ); // start with the global object
```

Comment: That'll do it.  Thanks.  I gotta start using forEach and builtins more.

Comment: Note that it does not enumerate nested arrays.