# Is it possible to find all defined Javascript objects which have a special pattern?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible in JavaScript (Or library JQuery) to find all (global) objects which have a given pattern ?

For example:

```
objekt_1
objekt_2 //Javascript objects

function find_objects() {
     return ....; //return all objects that start with "object"-prefix
}
```

Comment: why would you want to do that?if you create these objects, it makes more sense to put them inside an array.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409577/get-all-the-objects-dom-or-otherwise-using-javascript

Comment: @mpm Very good consideration. I want it because I'm not controll all the javascript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If they are global, they are stored in `window` object. Then you just need to filter them:

```
function find_objects() {
    var objs = [];
    for (var k in window) {
        var cVariable = window[k];
        if (/^objekt/.test(k) && typeof cVariable === "object") {
             objs.push(cVariable);
        }
    }
    return objs;
}
```

Demo:

```
> function find_objects() {
    var objs = [];
    for (var k in window) {
        if (/^objekt/.test(k) && typeof window[k] === "object") {
             objs.push(window[k]);
        }
    }
    return objs;
}
undefined
>find_objects()
[]
>var objekt_1 = {a: 1}
undefined
>find_objects()
[Object]
```

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/holarowa/1/edit)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Global variables in javascript are actually elements of the window object, so you can do this:

```
for(var i in window) {
    var ret = [];
    if(i.substr(0,7) == 'object_') ret.push(i);
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As they're globals, they're properties on the global object, which is referenced via the `window` variable on browsers. So you may be able to find them with a `for-in` loop:

```
var key;
for (key in window) {
    // Examine `key` here, it's a string; if it matches, do
    // something with `window[key]`, which is the value for that variable
}
```